# Help with accuracy of measurements (maybe normalisation?)

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, generalized-linear-model

So I have a large data set regarding honeybees. I have three measurements, activity count, internal temperature of a hive and external temperature outside a hive (also the time when measurements were taken, but that isn't important at this stage). Activity count is a pure count of bees.

Data set looks like:

Activity | 200, 500 , 1500, 2700, 4500, 3100, 2200, 1200 etc..

Ext Temp | 16°C, 19°C, 25°C, 28°C, 32°C, 29°C, 24°C, 19°C etc..

Int Temp | 34.4°C, 34.5°C, 34.4°C, 34.3°C, 34.5°C, 34.5°C etc..

There is a relationship between when bees exit the hive to forage and the temperature it is outside (the warmer it gets, the more they forage, up to a point). While this is already known, I want to "normalise" activity to temperature (normalise may not be the right word here, I am horrible at statistics but really wanting to get better). I want to be able to show that if there is a large deviation of activity (out of ordinary levels), it is not caused by a deviation in the temperature at the same time. The bees in my experiment have been exposed to pesticide, and we expect it to have an effect on activity rates. But before I can show a difference, I need to have a baseline for the levels of activity we would expect at certain temperatures before I can truly say a deviation of activity is apparent in the dataset. Hopefully this makes some sense?

Can anyone put me on the right track or have I been too vague?

Comment: Is this time series data? If you have a control treatment you probably should just fit a generalized linear model (possibly Poisson) including *Treatment* as a predictor and including an auto-correlation structure. I would not do the kind of "normalization" you are proposing.

Comment: it isn't in a time series format yet, but it technically could be time series data. The problem I see (maybe this isn't a problem) is that there are multiple points where data wasn't collected (due to machine failure). So there could be periods of 3-6 hours where no data is collected (my data was collected 24/7). The data set spans over 4 months, 24/7. I want to pull out specific time periods that we think the pesticide or other miticide may have effected, but it is hard to pull apart whether an effect is actually present. You think a GLM would be able to answer this kind of question?

Comment: Do you have a control? If you haven't I don't see how you intend to distinguish the effect of pesticides from other environmental or internal effects.

Comment: If you have time series data, you need time series models. A GLM with an auto-correlation structure is such a model and can deal with non-regular time series. Or you could impute the missing data and use time series models for regular time series.

Comment: Yes we have a control. I have two experimental sites, one with no exposure to pesticide, and another site with pesticide exposure. There is also different treatment levels within the exposure site. I want to take into account temperature as the main factor that effects activity, but I also want to add in other variables such as windspeed, rainfall etc. I guess these can be added as random factors into an analysis (this could be entirely wrong, just starting to get into stats). And I haven't converted the data to a time series yet, but it is entirely possible that I could.

Comment: My first thought was to do a repeated measures GLM, but I wasn't sure whether this was the right move. Someone then suggested that I need to compare activity to temperature as to get a baseline for what "normal" activity is. Apologies for turning this more into a discussion as I know that isn't what this site is meant for.